# How to show $dist(p,S) = 0$, then there exists a sequence in $S$ converging to $p$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $S \subset (M, d)$, where $(M,d)$ is a metric space

Let $dist(p,S) \equiv \inf\{d(p,s) | s \in S, p \in M\}$

I wish to show that if $dist(p,S) = 0$, then there exists a $(p_n)$ in $S$ converging to $p$ and $p$ is the limit point of $S$

Original attempt:

> Suppose $dist(p,S) = 0$, then $\inf\{d(p,s) | s \in S\} = 0$, then by
>   definition of metric $s = p$, hence $p \in S$, and is approached by
>   the constant sequence and $p$ is the limit point of $S$

But here the problem is that we are writing things in terms of the $\inf$, so $\inf\{d(p,s) | s \in S\} = 0 \not\Leftrightarrow d(p,s) = 0$

How should I proceed with this question...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $\epsilon>0$.  By the definition of $\inf$ there is a $s\in S$ such that $0\le d(p,s)<\epsilon$.  Can you get it from here?

Comment: We can then set $p_n = s$, let $\epsilon = 1/n$, then the sequence converges. But how did you get the $\epsilon$?  I thought the relationship was $\inf d(p,s) \leq d(p,s)$. How do you know that $d(p,s)$ is bounded above by $\epsilon$?

Comment: Suppose $S$ is a set of real numbers bounded below so that $\inf S$ exists.  Let $\inf S=a$.  Now for any $\epsilon>0$, $a+\epsilon$ is not a lower bound because $a$ the the greatest lower bound.  So, there is an $x\in S$ such that $a\le x<a+\epsilon$.